# How is the Lorenz attractor a fractal?

Tags: fractals

Based on my intuition of what a fractal is, the Lorenz attractor doesn't fit that category for me. A fractal should have some self similarity, but the attractor seems just like two two-dimensional disks which meet in the middle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Who claims that the Lorenz attractor is a fractal?

Comment: The Lorenz attractor is a well known fractal as google could easily illustrate. It seems to me a very fair question. To the point @grevel, first off, the Lorentz attractor exists in a 3D phase space. Presumably the "2D disks" you've seen are just projections of the real object. But I agree it is not obvious how the 3D object presents self-similarity.

Comment: See https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physd.2003.10.006

Comment: I suppose if your view of a fractal is "an extended entity which presents structure at arbitrarily small scales", the Lorenz attractor is obviously a fractal. But if your view is "an entity which exhibits self similarity across scales", it is not clear to me how the Lorenz attractor exhibits self similarity. These notes seem relevant https://www.southampton.ac.uk/~mb1a10/lect7.pdf

Comment: @kevinkayaks I have actually programmed some attractors and I am familiar with their structure. The attractor seems to me like a 2D manifold in a 3d space.

Comment: Mathematics works with *definitions*, not intuitions.  Whether or not the Lorenz attractor is a fractal depends *entirely* on how you define the word "fractal".  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2677204/